# HTML5 canvas drag events on iPhone (Safari or UIWebView)

Tags: iphone, html, safari, canvas, mousemove

I have a simple "drag to draw" doodle style HTML5/canvas implementation which uses the 'mousemove' event on the canvas. E.g.:

```
canvas.addEventListener( 'mousemove', drawingFunction, false );
```

This works fine on, say, Safari or FF on the desktop. However, when run on an iPhone, dragging only scrolls the webview around the screen.

Note that I've also tried out several other HTML5 drag-to-draw applets with Safari on the iPhone, and so far, they all seem to fail the same way.

Is it not possible to separate drag/mousemove events on the canvas from webview scroll events?

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ~think~ I found the solution:
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1867-Drawing-On-The-iPhone-Canvas-With-jQuery-And-ColdFusion.htm

Comment: UIWebView needs _touch_ events, not _mouse_ events! Sorry to have wasted anyone's time :)